# How to generate random numbers from a range in c#

Tags: c#, random, generator

So I need to generate random numbers based on user set parameters, and make a basic math expression. They have 3 options; single, double, or triple digit numbers. So based on that I need to generate a random number from 0 to 9, 0 to 99, and 0 to 100.

So far I've read about the `Random` class. This is my poor attempt:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int value = 0;

if (digits == 1)
{
    rnd.Next(value);
    q1Lbl.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+random+numbers+range

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need this overload of [Random.Next()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public virtual int Next(
    int minValue,
    int maxValue
)
```

Where:

> minValue = The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.
>
> maxValue = The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned.
>   maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.

Note the words **inclusive** and **exclusive** in the parameter descriptions.  This means the minimum value can be returned in the possible values, while the maximum value will **not** be possible.

This is further clarified in the description of the return value:

> Return Value - A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to
>   minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values
>   includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue,
>   minValue is returned.

For example, to get single digit values between 0 and 9 (inclusive), you'd use:

```
int value = rnd.Next(0, 10); // return a value between 0 and 9 inclusive
```

To get double digits, you'd use:

```
int value = rnd.Next(10, 100); // return a value between 10 and 99 inclusive
```

Finally, to get triple digit numbers, you'd use:

```
int value = rnd.Next(100, 1000); // return a value between 100 and 999 inclusive
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int single = rnd.Next(1, 10);  // 1 ~9
int double = rnd.Next(1, 100);    // 1~99
int triple = rnd.Next(1,101);      // 1~100
```

loop it if you want to achieve the values multiple times

Answer (score 0):

There's an overload of the `Next` method, you only have to pass the range:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.Next(1,20); //Gives you a number between 1 and 20
```

Here you find the entire documentation https://www.google.com.co/search?q=next+random+c%23&oq=next+random&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3144j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Not quite...that'll return numbers between 1 and 19 (inclusive).  The value of 20 will **not** be included in the possible return values.

Comment: Oh thanks guys, that clear it up a lot! Thanks a ton